Live video capture --> automatic processing --> projection or video streaming
I would like to capture a live video feed from a camcorder/camera, feed it into the computer (or cloud if it's easier), process the image with special effects (create a kaleidoscope effect), and then send the processed video feed (with limited but acceptable delay...*) to a projector (either via the cloud or at a minimum through an HDMI cable)
Is there a pre-defined set of software that would be best to use in terms of ingesting the feed, processing, and then distributing it? If one software can't do it, is
Does some software exist off the shelf which would be able to do this (ingestion, processing, and distribution)? If not, what about a set of multiple off-the shelf software running concurrently? Lastly, if none exist, are there specific python related packages and libraries which would be able to do this?
Are there any relevant pieces of hardware (special video capture) which would be more suited for this?
*For me, it's not so important that the processed output image is instantaneous with capture, a minute of delay would be okay, however I am looking for there to be some kind of continuous image flow and for the system to be able to run for hours.
